# How to select value form drop down list in selenium (Web-driver java):

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I want to select the value from the drop down (drop down values changes when i change the values of previous drop down on the same page.) i have tried but nothing happened.

Java Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//* @id='ctl00_CPHPageContents_rcbBranch_Input']")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
//search.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;">
    <input id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_ddlAssignedTo_Input" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" type="text" value="ghaffar, a" name="ctl00$CPHPageContents$ddlAssignedTo" autocomplete="off"/>
    </td>
```

Comment: What is the problem? code not working or thrown exception or any else?

Comment: Code is not working..

Answer (score 2):

Selenium has special class designed to interact with drop down lists called [Select](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html). From there you can easily choose option by id, index or displayed value.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
WebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.id("country"));

Select clickThis = new Select(dropDownListBox);

clickThis.selectByVisibleText("(+44) United Kingdom");
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

1st you deselected all the values in the multi select box then select the values which you want.. It is working properly..

```
Log.info("Clicking on Softwarepack dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor execu = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
execu.executeScript("document.getElementById('TestID').style.display='block';");
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("TestID")));
sel.deselectAll();
sel.selectByVisibleText("Value");
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this

```
public void(string[item])) {

    WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("countTd"));
    dropDown.click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='countTd']/span[text()='" + item + "']")).click();
}
```